# c++ what is the *clever* way of creating setup program and handle extraction

Tags: c++, installation, windows-installer, setup-project

**I know** how to **create** and code my own setup program but i need to be redirected at some point. This point i'm sure inlight other people too.

I created a setup project. All is done. Except, installation files inside of EXE.

I know 2 different ways of doing this:

1. Create resource in EXE and embed RAR/ZIP file.
2. Put compressed archive with files along with EXE. EXE will read contents and data from this protected and compressed ZIP.

But what i want is number **1**. I want to embed it. But;

1. What is the proper way of embedding this? Are other setup creators do the same thing? Embed resource as compressed single zip in EXE? Or do they another trick?
2. How do you extract files? On the fly by memory? Like read each file one-by-one. Synced. Or first, copy ZIP to temp and extract from it.
3. Or even embed all files separately to the resources.

I, even think that if i should create simple MSI without dialogs and embed it and run from background but i want to take all control. I want everything belongs to the original setup that i created.

Note:

> I want to make my own dialogs, effects, procedures, functions and
>   steps. Yes, MSI is acceptable but i will stick with its features. Oh,
>   If im able to extend it, why should i spent more time doing this
>   instead of making my own? I am so confused... I am talking about very big setup project here. Not just a standard ugly UI with less features. At least, im gonna try :)

**Do not give me any sample/code** just show me a correct path, please.

## Best options here:

1. Create ZIP compatible EXE that reads itself as ZIP and read the file list and extract.
2. Create non-zip compatible EXE that has a hidden body somewhere and read that area (seek) and get the list & extract.

Comment: I think there is no _'**the** proper way'_ to do it I'm afraid.

Comment: Then what is the closest or even clever way?

Comment: Why is your setup such a big project?  Do you really need to put that much into the installer?  Can some of it move to an in-app preferences UI type thing?

Comment: I will deploy my company software in this setup. Batteries included. So, it wont just install Next > Choose Component > Next > Installing > Finish. More clear, Special Activation Process, Communication with other PCs in the network, web appliances etc. With very nice UI look other than typical MSI. For example Windows Live Installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Best options here:

1. Create ZIP compatible EXE that reads itself as ZIP and read the file list and extract.
2. Create non-zip compatible EXE that has a hidden body somewhere and read that area (seek) and get the list & extract.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do it is to use the Windows installer technology, aka MSI.  There is a nice, Microsoft blessed toolset called WiX that you can use to greatly simplify the process.

http://wix.codeplex.com/

Comment: I want to make my own dialogs, effects, procedures, functions and steps. Yes, MSI is acceptable but i will stick with its features. Oh, If im able to extend it, why should i spent more time doing this instead of making my own? I am so confused...

Comment: Well, MSI supports all of that.  I'm sure more qualified experts can tell you why MSI is better than other options... probably something to do with proper transactioning, uninstall and all that.

Comment: I thought making my own setup program is easy then playing with MSI coding structure.

Comment: Yeah, MSI isn't easy.  Remember it is declarative, not a program.  Don't be afraid to contract with the [experts](http://www.firegiant.com/).

Comment: If we eliminate this difficulty. Do you have any recommendation on my original question?

Answer (score 1):

If you are truly intent on reinventing the wheel, you can look through the source code to WiX on how things are done.

Answer (score 0):

Why write your own? Much easier to use WiX (http://wixtoolset.org/) with optionally a graphical interface like WiXEdit (http://wixedit.sourceforge.net/). Have you thought about additional requirements like uninstall etc...

Good luck!

Comment: I will deploy my company software in this setup. Batteries included. So, it wont just install Next > Choose Component > Next > Installing > Finish. More clear, Special Activation Process, Communication with other PCs in the network, web appliances etc. With very nice UI look other than typical MSI. For example Windows Live Installer. **But i think i can do this UI preferences with WiXEdit.**

Answer (score 0):

Would [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) help with your problem? You can personalise the dialogs and extend its functionality quite a lot.